# How to seprated by comma number elements and remove empty string in javascript

Tags: javascript, split, slice

below are one of the examples that you can seprated by comma each element and also remove empty elements

```
var p = ",32111_10589,32111_10591,32111_10593,32111_10613,32111_10590,32111_10592,32111_10594,32111_10614,32111_10595,32111_10593_5673,32111_10593_5674,32111_10590_5651,32111_10592_5669,32111_10594_5671,32111_10614_5687,32111_10590_5652,32111_10592_5670,32111_10594_5672,32111_10614_5688,32111_10595_5675,32111_10595_5676,";

  // remove first and last element from array and seprated elements by comma.
  var ar = p.slice(1,-1).split(',');
```

Comment: I tried splice also but don't get solution.

Answer (score 4):

First you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `,` and the using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the empty string

You might wonder what exactly is `.filter(s => s)`. It filter out the empty string because `""` is considered as `falsy` value.

If `s` is `empty string` then it is filtered out else included in the final result.

```js
var p =
  ",32111_10589,32111_10591,32111_10593,32111_10613,32111_10590,32111_10592,32111_10594,32111_10614,32111_10595,32111_10593_5673,32111_10593_5674,32111_10590_5651,32111_10592_5669,32111_10594_5671,32111_10614_5687,32111_10590_5652,32111_10592_5670,32111_10594_5672,32111_10614_5688,32111_10595_5675,32111_10595_5676,";

var arr = p.split(",").filter(s => s);
console.log(arr);
```

But there is a case that won't cover is if there is a empty space in between `,` then you can use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```js
var p = " ,32111, ";

var arr = p.split(",").filter(s => s.trim());
console.log(arr);
```